# Windows Phone 8 - Sharing data between users

Tags: networking, windows-phone-8

I'm writing a small app that I would like to be able to quickly share arbitrary data between users. I'm not sure of the best way to do this - do I need to set-up a service separately, or have both a client and service within the app itself?

I want a user to be able to select a friend and share their status with them instantly - so I guess a chat type architecture would be ok for this - I'm just not sure of the API's required, nor am I sure of the actual client/server architecture.

Comment: This is a way to broad question. You would be much better off studying how to create a typical server based chat application using either one of many books available, or one of the million tutorials on the internet. Stack Overflow is a Q&A forum, and this is a "teach me everything" type question, which doesn't match the profile of the site.

Comment: No, I was just after some guidance and direction on which options are available. I come from a desktop background - hence not being very familiar with Windows Phone. Thanks for your helpful input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options and there is no best option. It all depends on your specific requirements.

In general, you will need a client app that runs on the phone and then some sort of online web service where both parties can talk to and that service can handle pushing communication between connected clients.

However, for a chat application [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) comes to mind. It provides real-time web functionality. I think there is even a WP chat sample application on their website.

Comment: Thank you very much - just the sort of help I was after.